# Tag to request help with your question's title, tags or vocabulary

Tags: discussion, tags

Every once in a while I have a problem I want to solve where I can write out the description text  and explain in detail the background/cause/problem and what I need help with.
But then I have one of these recurring problems

- I have no clue how to summarize the question into the Title so that people reading it know what's going on
- I don't know what tags are to be assigned other than the most general, like programming language
- I'm describing something that has a simple term that I don't know and I'm beating around the bush

In these cases I think that if someone who knows what my problem is I would welcome there help editing  my question to be more general so to be able to help people with similar questions in the future.
Not so much community wiki but more of a I know my questions is a bad question and I'd like help improving my questions.

Some of my questions i wished could have been clearer in the title

- [Special unique columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455010/special-unique-columns)
- [Reduce number of times an event gets fired? [bad/incorrect title - change if you have a better one]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323386/reduce-number-of-times-an-event-gets-fired-bad-incorrect-title-change-if-you)
- [Can select next record alphabetically, but what happens when the record name is identical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255139/can-select-next-record-alphabetically-but-what-happens-when-the-record-name-is-i)
- [Complex update using joins and group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743797/complex-update-using-joins-and-group-by)
- [Assign 1 arbitrary row as primary per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763052/assign-1-arbitrary-row-as-primary-per-group)

Comment: Do you not notice that this happens automatically *most* of the time? Michael's already made the same point. I spend a lot of time trying to clean up and improve questions, whether from new users or experienced users. I know others do the same. It seems like this should take care of itself, without needing any additional visual clutter. I'm honestly curious if you've had a different experience.

Answer (score 3):

There are many community members (*cough* like me *cough*) who watch new questions as they come in, and clean them up as best we can. I don't think we need a special mechanism for this.